# How does Comma separated files work? ...if the text has commas in it

Tags: csv

I never understood this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipdedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_Rules) has the info you want

> Fields with embedded commas must be enclosed within double-quote characters.

Comment: Excel uses 'List separator' value from user locale settings. So in Russia that would be ';' instead of ','.

Answer (score 2):

For more than you ever want to know about CSV: [RfC4180 - Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](http://RfC-Editor.Org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is quite complete.

> Fields that contain a special
>   character (comma, newline, or double
>   quote), must be enclosed in double
>   quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real standard for what people tell csv files.
Mirosoft refers to csv as **c**haracter **s**eparated **v**alues.

This is done because dependent on the decimal character the separated character is changed.

```
German:  1,2
English: 1.2
```

But I aggree that most times " of ' is used to enclose text elements.
But either all strings are enclosed in " or none.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is very far from standardised. The nearest approach to it is [this RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt), which explains how commas and other special characters should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Quote the field (use " character e.g. "..., ...")
- Change your delimiter from comma "," to something else (e.g. ";")

See this [webpage with an introduction and overview of CSV (comman separated values) format for more](http://data.okfn.org/standards/csv)